# jqGrid.GetRowData with Id from double click throwing exception

Tags: exception, jqgrid

I have a work flow...

```
ondblClickRow: function (id) {
            debugger;
            var rowData = $("#list").getRowData(id);
...
}
```

This function call is throwing an exception whereas it previously worked.  Actually stepping into the mini-fied code I can see that there is an array out of bounds exception of sorts.  There are only seven columns and it appears to be calling an eighth (zero indexed-I have columns from 0-6, and it appears to be asking for a seventh).  Not sure what is going on in that particular exception.  I am still researching, but this was working fine and I did not change anything related to this in weeks.  AM I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hack work around, but I simply just got the cell values that I needed based on the id and the column names that I needed so I could circumvent any issue that might be occuring... Even though I am not sure what happened.  I am still very curious as to why this occured.  More research will need to be done for me to be more comfortable with this solution...

```
var FName = $('#list').getCell(id, 'First_Name');
```